# vscode: how to just format indent?

Tags: format, visual-studio-code, indent

I want to use vscode to format my js code. But I just want it to format indent, not any other space in my statement.

But I have not found any way to control this config.

e.g.: If I have some code like this(where the colons is aligned but no indent):

```
let o = {
a                   : 1,
the_long_item_here  : 2,
};
```

I want vscode to format the indent like this(just add indent but colons still aligned):

```
let o = {
    a                   : 1,
    the_long_item_here  : 2,
};
```

But actually vscode give me the result:

```
let o = {
    a: 1,
    the_long_item_here: 2,
};
```

where the indent is done well, but the colons alignment is lost.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You’ll have to install a third party extension for that. There are several to pick from.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving you project file as a .js or desired file extension. Visual studio code will automatically apply indentation and other formatting based on the criteria for the file extension type.

Comment: My question is how to apply just indentation but no other formatting.